# Powershell to delete all files with a certain file extension

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I want to scan a directory (there are no subs) and delete any file with an extension of `.avi`  I tried this syntax, but no errors are thrown, and no files are deleted.  This is the code I tried

```
get-childitem 'C:\Users\ramrod\Desktop\Firefly' -include *.avi | foreach ($_) {remove-item $_.fullname}
```

What should be altered in order to delete all the `.avi` files from the folder?

Comment: What prevents you from using `rm *.avi`? (Yes, that's valid PowerShell syntax because `rm` is an alias of `del`.

Comment: Technically, `rm` and `del` are both aliases of the `Remove-Item` cmdlet.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use `del *.<extension>` or one of it's aliases (like `rm`, if you are more used to bash).

So it would be `del *.avi` to delete all files ending in `.avi` in the current working directory.

Use `del <directory>\*.<extension>` to delete files in other directories.

---

**WARNING:** Both `del *.<extension>` and `del <directory>\*.<extension>` will delete other extensions that match the pattern. These files are not sent to the Recycle Bin.

Example: `del *.doc*` deletes ***.doc**, ***.docm** and ***.docx**. The `del <directory>\*.<extension>` works in a similar fashion.

Comment: To recursively do this `ls *.avi -Recurse | foreach {rm $_}`

Comment: To recursively do this for hidden files `ls *.ini -Recurse -Force | foreach {rm -Force $_}`

Answer (score 40):

Assuming the preferred method of opening a Powershell instance in the directory, a generic version would be as follows:

```
Get-ChildItem *.avi | foreach { Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName }
```

For a directory-specific version:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\ramrod\Desktop\Firefly\' *.avi | foreach { Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName }
```

Add in `-Recurse` to `Get-ChildItem` to affect all contained folders.

Example:

```
Get-ChildItem *.avi -Recurse | foreach { Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName }
```

Answer (score 35):

The [Remove-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item) Cmdlet should be all you need. Just pass the root folder where the avi files exist and pass the `-Recurse` parameter along with a filter:

```
Remove-Item 'C:\Users\ramrod\Desktop\Firefly\*' -Recurse -Include *.avi
```

This should execute faster than finding the files via `Get-ChildItem` and invoking `Remove-Item` for each one.

- Adding the `-WhatIf` switch will list the items that would be deleted but the actual deletion is not performed.
- Adding the `-Confirm` switch will prompt you before deleting each file, which is safer for people less comfortable with **PowerShell**.

Comment: Not sure why this answer got a down-vote. The `-WhatIf` switch is unnecessary. I submitted an edit to this answer. +1 The `Remove-Item` commandlet is all you need, and runs faster than the currently accepted answer.

Comment: It's a good idea to use `-whatif` to verify you will remove only the files you want to remove. And especially when offering up a deletion command to those of unknown technical expertise. Best to keep the training wheels on.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there are several text files in current directory.
`dir * -include *.txt` & `dir *.txt` work as expected but `dir -include *.txt` gives nothing. The reason is well explained on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1370251).

Corrected command:
`dir 'C:\Users\ramrod\Desktop\Firefly\*.avi' | foreach {del $_}`

Answer (score 0):

This finally did it for me - tried all above and nada.

```
get-childitem "<drive>:\<folder>" -recurse -force -include *.<ext> | remove-item -force
```

sure two -force is not required but that is what is working so that is what I am sticking with.

Answer (score 0):

`del *.raw, *.log, *.op.raw` // delete desired type of files. It deletes all files with .raw, .log, .op.raw extension in pwd

`ls *.raw, *.log, *.op.raw` // see desired type of files

Answer (score 0):

```
$patho = $env:USERPROFILE + '\Downloads\'
foreach($due in gci $patho -name "*.avi" )
{
$monk = $patho + $due
remove-item -path $monk
}
```

Already answered... just elaborating...using these sorts of codes:
Can cause a user / you to accidently permanently delete your own folders by mistake.
Quite fundamentally, avoid using remove-item, unless you are certain of recovery or process. A simple dash '' being missed and '*' combined can cause quite the heartache.
What you should do to delete sets: Treat as if networking.

1. Count the number of items you going through, directories or not.
2. Consider system items associated with counting list.
3. Consider the count sets as safe to go through or not. (i.e. are you trying to delete multiple items or multiple directories? Probably not the latter) Cancel if multiple directories are in the path of deletion.
4. Use Move-Item as much as you can, and -whatif or -confirm parameters instead to be sure you don't delete your own user profile.
5. I always end up deleting my profile somehow anyways!

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
Remove-Item "C:\Users\ramrod\Desktop\*.avi"
```

Comment: hey there, this doesn't seem to remove avi files, and it doesn't seem to do it from the folder in question, either. Could you improve on this answer or explain how it might help in this situation ?